# How to mount HDD after upgrading SSD?

Tags: boot, ssd, bios, upgrade, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron 15 7567 and I changed the SSD card. From factory it has an SSD for the main OS and a HDD for storage.

After changing the SSD I used the factory reset USB but I did not noticed windows was being installed on the HDD because the SSD was not formatted yet.

Since I changed the SSD when I factory reset I had to follow these [steps from Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/ja-jp/000132465/windows-10-install-with-nvme-ssd-and-sata-drives?lang=en). It installed correctly Windows the second time. After that, I activated again the HDD and the boot system had now two Windows installations. So I boot with the SSD, formatted the HDD with diskmgmt and the boot system crashed.

I had to follow [this](https://www.easeus.com/amp/computer-instruction/fix-a-required-drive-partition-is-missing-windows-10.html#1) and [this](https://recoverit.wondershare.com/windows-tips/path-not-found.html) in order to re mount all the drives and then I followed [steps from Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/ja-jp/000132465/windows-10-install-with-nvme-ssd-and-sata-drives?lang=en) again. Now after the 3rd installation, I have Windows in the SSD but the HDD is not mounted.

I think I have to do something in the BIOS but I don’t want to mess it again. So after [steps from Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/ja-jp/000132465/windows-10-install-with-nvme-ssd-and-sata-drives?lang=en) I already activated SATA-0 and SATA-1 but the HDD is still not available, I can

1. Disable legacy options roms
2. Set SATA operation to RAID ON

I don’t know what to do from here (1 or 2?) as I don’t want to crash the boot system again. At this point HDD is empty, I erased all the partitions before installing the third time.

**EDIT 1**

For 1) I disabled legacy options roms and now I can see the HDD in Windows.

For 2) the RAID on, I left it as AHCI as explained [here](https://www.dell.com/community/Windows-10/Help-Dual-boot-Raid-on-or-AHCI/td-p/7426775) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963087/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-and-raid-on) since it seems RAID on will make bootable USBs for Ubuntu unable to see the SDD and later I want to do a dual boot.

Comment: I disabled the legacy options roms and now I can see the HDD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For 1) I disabled legacy options roms and now I can see the HDD in Windows.

For 2) the RAID on, I left it as AHCI as explained [here](https://www.dell.com/community/Windows-10/Help-Dual-boot-Raid-on-or-AHCI/td-p/7426775) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/963087/install-dual-boot-ubuntu-with-windows-10-and-raid-on) since it seems RAID on will make bootable USBs for Ubuntu unable to see the SDD and later I want to do a dual boot.